# ifup gives "misplaced option"

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip

When I run `ifup ens33`, I get this error:

```
/etc/network/interfaces:5: misplaced option
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

the result when trying to restart network is

```
midhun@server:~$ systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-03-18 18:17:52 IST; 16min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 6615 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6612 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && u
 Main PID: 6615 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 18 18:17:52 server.example.com systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Mar 18 18:17:52 server.example.com sh[6612]: /etc/network/interfaces:5: misplaced option
Mar 18 18:17:52 server.example.com sh[6612]: ifquery: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
Mar 18 18:17:52 server.example.com ifup[6615]: /etc/network/interfaces:5: misplaced option
Mar 18 18:17:52 server.example.com ifup[6615]: /sbin/ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
Mar 18 18:17:52 server.example.com systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 18 18:17:52 server.example.com systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 18 18:17:52 server.example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

I tried rebooting the system several times but no luck please help me

This the configuration of my network interface...Please help me

```
midhun@server:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto ens33
ifname ens33 inet static
address 192.168.1.25
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 3):

That reads `ifname`, not `iface` in line 5.

Comment: Richer changed now it looks like this
https://paste.debian.net/1189843/

getting error as   /etc/network/interfaces:3: misplaced option
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"

Comment: The other way 'round: `iface` is correct.

Comment: Read the [manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html). There is no directive `ifname`. I believe @SimonRichter's answer is correct. Replace all occurrences of `ifname` with `iface`. By the way, instead of putting text in external paste bins, why don't you just update the question?